# Creation of a Function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to create two functions but I am having trouble. The first consists of converting degrees Fahrenheit to Kelvin using this formula `(F - 32)*(5/9) + 273` and another calculates the cricket chirping rate (in `s^-1`) using Dolbear's law which is `Tf=40+N15` where `Tf` is the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit and `N15` is the rate of chirps per minute.

I was able to make the temperature function.

```
f[F_] = (F - 32)*(5/9) + 273
```

I am just having trouble with the second function.

Thanks,
L

Comment: Probably `N15` is the number of chirps produced in 15 seconds (from Wikipedia article), so chirping rate is `rate[Tf_] := (Tf - 40)/15`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article, the formula is simply number of chirps in 15 seconds plus 40.  Don't know why you would need a special function for that, but it would be:

```
chirpsToTemp[n_]:=n+40
```

Also, in your original post you really should have a colon before your equals sign

```
toKelvin[f_]:=((f-32)*(5/9))+273
```